# UIStackView inside a UICollectionViewCell is out of screen

Tags: autolayout, interface-builder, uistackview

I'm trying to use a `UIStackView` in my `cell`, but I'm with some problems with the constraints.

When I put the constraints in my stack, the whole content go to outside the view. Note in my screenshots:

[image: without contraints]

this first one is the `UIStackView` without any constraint. Note, the content has a margin of 5.

[image]

now, I've set the constraint in my `UIStackView`. Note that margin right of content doesn't exists anymore. And now its a negative margin.
Obs: the distribution is fill proportionally

Anyone knows what Im doing wrong?

Comment: you should check how the layout works during runtime .. interface builder sometimes buggy with UIStackView...

Comment: yeah, in runtime still the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Everything works just fine. Make sure you have added constraints to all other elements.

[image: Everything works just fine]

Inside `UIView` with margins:

[image]

Comment: Yeap, you can try to embed all with a `UIView` and put a margin on it? Without the margin, everything looks fine. My problem is with margins

Comment: its like the right margin don`t work but the left one works.

Comment: works fine! I think I got whats causing the problem: My labels is more than 1 line. When I put 1 line, stay perfect. When put 0/+1 the margin goes away

Comment: I think I`ll need to put this labels inside a UIView to works